# How to make Cufon print

Tags: printing, wysiwyg, sifr, cufon

Is it possible to make cufon print like you see on screen? WYSIWYG? (What You See Is What You Get when you print a hard copy?) Right now, it prints the fonts in the CSS, but not the embedded cufon... Thanks for considering! (I doubt this can be done--please prove me wrong!)

(And what about sIFR for that matter?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will be of any help but check to see that you've defined a separate print stylesheet which includes the font. As you would expect items from your screen/projector stylesheet will be lost in printing.

Answer (score 0):

according to this you can't do it by default due to it not printing out well

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cufon/ki8XbJOcAP0

I have found another thread pointing to a version where you can print. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cufon/XWEff0jCyFc

...but this is taken from an old cufon before the retina fix and any other bits that might have been improved on.

I have found though that it prints out OK as long as the colour is dark enough